# Type hints for classes with known supertype

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, python-3.8

Using Python 3.8. I have the following stripped-down example that I haven't fully gotten to typecheck:

```
class A(ABC):
  property: str

  def implemented(self, arg: str) -> None:
    self.property = arg

  @abstractmethod
  def not_implemented(self, another_arg: int) -> int:
     pass


def method_decorator(f: Callable[[??, int], int]) -> Callable[[??, int], int]:
  @wraps(f)
  def wrapper(self: ??, arg: int) -> int:
    # do stuff

  return wrapper


class SubA(A):
  @method_decorator
  def not_implemented(self, another_arg: int) -> int:
    return another_arg


list_of_a_impls: List[??] = [SubA]


def takes_callback(f: Callable[[int], int]) -> int:
  return f(3)


def do_something_with_an_a() -> None:
  cls: ?? = list_of_a_impls[0]
  a_inst: ?? = cls()

  takes_callback(a_inst.not_implemented) # partial application giving problems
```

I was able to resolve everything except `do_something_with_an_a` by introducing a `Protocol` that looks very similar to `A`. However, I'm worried that I shouldn't actually need a protocol given that I really only want to allow subclasses of `A`. Regardless of that, I still wasn't able to come up with a type hint that would let me use `cls` to instantiate an object. What's the right thing to do here?

Comment: As a side note, `property` is probably a bad name for an attribute, since it shadows the builtin `property` in the class body and will cause type checking issues if you every try to add a property.

Answer (score 0):

Your code type-checks as written if you just fill-in the `??`s with `A`, `type[A]`, or a bounded TypeVar as applicable:

```
from __future__ import annotations

from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from functools import wraps
from typing import Callable, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", bound="A")


class A(ABC):
    property: str

    def implemented(self, arg: str) -> None:
        self.property = arg

    @abstractmethod
    def not_implemented(self, another_arg: int) -> int:
        ...


def method_decorator(f: Callable[[T, int], int]) -> Callable[[T, int], int]:
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(self: A, arg: int) -> int:
        return 123

    return wrapper


class SubA(A):
    @method_decorator
    def not_implemented(self, another_arg: int) -> int:
        return another_arg


list_of_a_impls: list[type[A]] = [SubA]


def takes_callback(f: Callable[[int], int]) -> int:
    return f(3)


def do_something_with_an_a() -> None:
    cls: type[A] = list_of_a_impls[0]
    a_inst: A = cls()

    takes_callback(a_inst.not_implemented)
```

This pass type checking with `mypy --python-version 3.8 --strict`.

You should also consider avoiding shadowing the builtin [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) in the class body, and using [standard 4-space indentation](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#indentation).

Comment: I wonder if mypy and pyre diverge here. From pyre I get `Cannot instantiate abstract class A with abstract method not_implemented` when trying to instantiate `a_inst`.